# Parse a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

```
b={   'cricket': {   'Arts & Entertainment': [{'id': '6003760631113'},
                                               {'id': '6003350271605'},
                                               {'id': '6003106646578'},
                                               {'id': '6003252371486'},
                                               {'id': '6003370637135'}]},
'News, Media & Publications': [   {'id': '6003020834693'},
                                                     {'id': '6003139266461'},
                                                     {'id': '6003716669862'},
                                                     {'id': '6002971085794'},
                                                     {'id': '6003172932634'}]
}
```

How to parse this nested dictionary in order to retrieve all the id inside this nested list?

I have tried this:

```
for j in b['cricket']:
    print(j)
```

which gives me this results:-

Arts & Entertainment

Then I tried this:

```
for j in b['cricket']:
    for k in j:
        print(k['id'])
```

which is giving me this error:-
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eacbv.png)

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
ids = [int(row['id']) for row in b['cricket']['Arts & Entertainment']]
```

will give you a list of the numbers,

```py
[6003760631113, 6003350271605, 6003106646578, 6003252371486, 6003370637135]
```

And for your new edits;

```py
ids = [int(row['id']) for row in b['cricket']['Arts & Entertainment'] + b['News, Media & Publications']]
```

Comment: Please check again. I have modified the question and your earlier solutions worked, but I kept getting errors when I tried to replicate the same for the entire dictionary. ```ids = [int(row['id']) for row,key,sub in b[key][sub]]```

Comment: Do you want a single list containing all ids from every category combined? like `[6003760631113, 6003350271605, 6003106646578, 6003252371486, 6003370637135, 6003020834693, 6003139266461, 6003716669862, 6002971085794, 6003172932634]` as ouput?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for i in b['cricket']['Arts & Entertainment']:
    print(i['id'])
```

```
6003760631113
6003350271605
6003106646578
6003252371486
6003370637135
```